# Wordpress trying to query two custom types to get child from the parent

Tags: custom-post-types, php, loop

So basically I have these service categories, under that there are the actual services. I am basically trying to loop through the categories and display category title, then underneath that I want to loop through all of the corresponding child items. I'm using "Toolset" custom field plugin with Wordpress. I have the loop working for the "Service Categories" and now I am trying to loop through the "Service Categories" children custom post type of "Services".

Codewise this is what I have right now:

```
<?php
            $loop = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'service-category']);
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            ?>

                <h2 class="title">
                    <?php echo the_title(); ?>
                    <?php if(types_render_field('subtitle')) {?>
                      <span class="subtitle"><?php echo types_render_field('subtitle');?></span>
                    <?php }?>
                </h2>


                <?php
                $loop2 = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'service', 'post_parent' => get_the_ID()]);
                ?>

                <?php while ( $loop2->have_posts() ) : $loop2->the_post();?>

                <h2 class="title">
                    <?php echo the_title(); ?>
                    <?php if(types_render_field('subtitle')) {?>
                      <span class="subtitle"><?php echo types_render_field('subtitle');?></span>
                    <?php }?>
                </h2>

                <?php endwhile;?>


          <?php endwhile; ?>
```

This is a screenshot of how I am associating the child custom post "Service" to the parent "Services-Category".

[image]

`$loop2` is where I am having the trouble trying to get the associated child items. How can I accomplish this? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated, I've burnt through two days searching for docs and all I find is the way to do it through the ui and not a template method.

@JacobPeattie When I look in the database to see the relationships I was able to find this:

[image]

So `36` is the parent `Service Category` post_id and `43` is the child `Service` post_id in the `post_meta` table. I was able to find the relationship I just have never done a `meta_query()`

Comment: This depends on how Toolset's "Post Relationship" field works, so you should consult with them.

But your code assumes that the value selected there is saved as the `post_parent` of the post. I don't think this is a safe assumption, as posts typically cannot have a parent of a different post type. It seems likely to me that that this relationship would be saved as *meta*, so instead of querying `post_parent` in `$loop2`, you probably need to be doing a meta query for the custom field value.

Comment: @JacobPeattie I should, but I'm using the free version so they prolly won't help much. I left on update on the question to answer how the relationship is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've posted, we can see that the Service -> Service Category relationship is saved as post meta. So what you want to do is query posts that have the `_wpcf_belongs_service-category_id` meta value that matches the ID of the Service Category you're looking for.

So instead of querying `post_parent`, which is looking at the `post_parent` column of the posts table, not meta, you need to add a *meta query*. The documentation for that is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters), but for your example you want to change

```
$loop2 = new WP_Query(['post_type' => 'service', 'post_parent' => get_the_ID()]);
```

To this:

```
$loop2 = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'service', 
    'meta_key' => '_wpcf_belongs_service-category_id',
    'meta_value' => get_the_ID(),
]);
```

Comment: I think you're mostly right, the only other part was that you had to add the `toolset_relationships` part. If you update your answer with that I delete my answer and mark yours correct!

Comment: That shouldn't be required based on the way the data is stored, but `toolset_relationships` is likely provided by the plugin to facilitate queries on more complex relationships (and allow the developers to change how data is stored without affecting existing code).

Comment: Ok I'll try running that without and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

So I was finally able to find what I needed:

```
                $loop2 = new WP_Query([
                  'post_type' => 'service',
                  'numberposts' => -1,
                  'meta_key' => '_wpcf_belongs_service-category_id',
                  'toolset_relationships' => [
                    'role' => 'child',
                    'related_to' => $parent_id,
                    'relationship' => ['service-category', 'service']
                  ]
                ]);
```

https://wp-types.com/documentation/customizing-sites-using-php/displaying-child-posts/